# Two forms submitting values

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have two forms on html page

```
<form name="a" action="add.php" class="a" method="post">
    XYZ?<br />
    <div class="radio">
    <i>
    <input type="radio" name="n" value="1">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="n" value="2">No
    <br>
    </i>
    </div>
</form>

<form name="b" action="add.php" class="b" method="post">
    XYZ<br />
    <div class="radio">
    <i>
    <input type="radio" name="odp" value="1">1 - Bad
    <input type="radio" name="odp" value="2">2 - Poor
    <input type="radio" name="odp" value="3">3 - Fair
    <input type="radio" name="odp" value="4">4 - Good
    <input type="radio" name="odp" value="5">5 - Excellent
    <br>
    </i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then i submit them with one button with javascript because i dont know how to do it in different way

```
<div class="confirm" onClick="submitForms()">
    <a href="#" >Confirm</a>
</div>

<script>
    submitForms = function(){
        document.forms["a"].submit();
        document.forms["b"].submit();
    }
</script>
```

When i go to add.php i get wrong values from forms like 0 and correct value

```
$n= $_POST['n'];
$odp = $_POST['odp'];
```

Do you know why?

Comment: can you submit two forms at once?

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time. Either combine them, or use ajax

Comment: Is there a reason you have them separated into 2 forms. If you are submitting at same time why not just combine and submit. You can have the fields spread out however you want as long as they are all contained in the form tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms don't submit fields from OTHER `<form>...</form>` tags. They only submit the fields that are defined within themselves.

You can also not submit multiple forms at the same time.

So whichever form's `<submit>` button gets pushed determines WHICH of the fields is submitted. If you click submit on the `n` form, you get the `n` value. If you click the odb submit, you get the odp value. Never vice-versa.

Submitting a form is essentially the same as clicking a link on the page - the browser immediately starts loading the target link, and leaves the current page. So your `a.submit()` starts that action, and likely the `b.submit()` never gets a chance to execute.